# How to refresh OLE DB Destination Editor Table Selection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I'm in a standard SQL Server Integration Services Package.  I have created a connection to my local db instance.  I drop a data flow task and then using a OLE DB source and Destination, I start creating my expected simple data flow.

Problem: I create a new table to dump my data from the source in SSMS and go back to visual studio's and look for it in the OLE DB Destination -- Name of the Table or the view drop down menu option and it's not there.

How do I refresh the cache without needing to close the ENTIRE program and reopen it?

I've asked some colleagues and they say they just close the entire program and reopen.  So, at my work, I'm not the only person having this problem.

What doesn't seem to work:

- Tried to change connections in the drop down
- Tried to delete the destination connection and recreate
- Close the package and reopen
- Close the solution and reopen
- CTRL+SHIFT+R

What has worked:

- Close the entire program, visual studios, and reopen

This hints to me that it's somehow cached in visual studios.

Is there a easier way?  I feel like there has to be... this is just silly that I have to close the entire program each time I add a table ... I reject this reality and wish to create my own!

Comment: Added a few more things I've tried.  I've also tried to google for this answer and nothing really comes up.  Some of it is on column changes but not really table adds.

Comment: Also, I wanted to mention I'm on the latest visual studio's install.  Version 15.9.16.  I do know that older versions, way back when, didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that you are not working in [offline mode](https://anthonymmartin.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/ssis-and-work-offline/).

If you are not working offline, just try to change the selected connection manager from the drop down list and re-select the initial one, or just change the data access mode and re-select the initial one. I think this may force refreshing the tables in the list.

Comment: I checked to see if I was working offline and it is not checked.  I also tried to click to another connection and back and that didn't do it either.